# Format JSON Body for Retrofit from single string value without model

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Is there a way to turn a single String value *(plain text, not json)* into a JSON body with an annotation? I do not want to create such a simple model.

**Example**

```
@POST("foo/{fooId}/bars")
Observable<Void> postBar(@Path("fooId") String styleId, @Body BarModel bar);

class BarModel {
    public String bar;
}
```

Will give me what I expect:

```
{
    "bar" : "hello world"
}
```

Is there a simple way to do it with an annotation? Something like this:

```
@POST("foo/{fooId}/bars")
Observable<Void> postBar(@Path("fooId") String styleId, @Body("bar") String bar);
```

Comment: See also this [meta-discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327487/230513).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Retrofit has a `Converter.Factory` abstract class that you can use to do custom HTTP representation. You can create a Converter to construct a `okhttp.RequestBody` if the method has a specific annotation.

The end result will look like:

```
@POST("/")
Call<Void> postBar(@Body @Root("bar") String foo)
```

and transform: `postBar("Hello World")`
into `{ "bar" : "Hello World" }`.

Let's get started.

Step 1 - create an annotation for the root key (Root.java)

```
/**
 * Denotes the root key of a JSON request.
 * <p>
 * Simple Example:
 * <pre><code>
 * &#64;POST("/")
 * Call&lt;ResponseBody&gt; example(
 *     &#64;Root("name") String yourName);
 * </code></pre>
 * Calling with {@code foo.example("Bob")} yields a request body of
 * <code>{name=>"Bob"}</code>.
 * @see JSONConverterFactory
 */
@Documented
@Target(PARAMETER)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Root {
  /**
   * The value of the JSON root.
   * Results in {"value" : object}
   */
  String value();
}
```

Step 2 - define your Converter.Factory that detects the annotation (JSONConverterFactory.java). I'm using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for JSON parsing but you can use whatever framework you want.

```
/**
 * Converts @Root("key") Value to {"key":json value} using the provided Gson converter.
 */
class JSONConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
    private final Gson gson;
    private static final MediaType CONTENT_TYPE =
            MediaType.parse("application/json");

    JSONConverterFactory(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(
            Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        for (Annotation annotation : parameterAnnotations) {
            if (annotation instanceof Root) {
                Root rootAnnotation = (Root) annotation;
                return new JSONRootConverter<>(gson, rootAnnotation.value());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private final class JSONRootConverter<T> implements Converter<T, RequestBody> {
        private Gson gson;
        private String rootKey;

        private JSONRootConverter(Gson gson, String rootKey) {
            this.gson = gson;
            this.rootKey = rootKey;
        }

        @Override
        public RequestBody convert(T value) throws IOException {
            JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(value);
            JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
            object.add(this.rootKey, element);
            return RequestBody.create(CONTENT_TYPE, this.gson.toJson(object));
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3 - install the JSONConverterFactory into your Retrofit instance

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); // Or your customized version
Retrofit.Builder builder = ...;
builder.addConverterFactory(new JSONConverterFactory(gson))
```

Step 4 - Profit

```
@POST("/")
Call<Void> postBar(@Body @Root("bar") String foo)
```

Or for your case:

```
@POST("foo/{fooId}/bars")
Observable<Void> postBar(@Body @Root("bar") String barValue, @Path("fooId") String styleId);
```

Comment: "Core" retrofit is an http client (and only that$. I did ask them about including better JSON support in the core library and they weren't interested. Retrofit was explicitly designed to be extended so this is the "right" approach according to the designers.

Comment: @Nick, is there anything else which would make this answer better/any reason you don't want to accept it yet?

Comment: I was hoping there would be a one-liner solution for my problem having to extend this much is overkill. However I'll accept it because it's likely to help others

Comment: Not an overkill at all. This is suitable dynamic solution that works as intended. Thank you Kevin!

Answer (score 2):

It does not necessarily create a json body, but your api might be able to work with url encoded things

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("foo/{fooId}/bars")
Observable<Void> postBar(@Path("fooId") String styleId, @Field("bar") String bar);
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't tried. It's not an API I have control of, so is expecting a json body like the one I posted. (This gave me bar=hello%20world)

Comment: you can still try that out, this can be used instead of body quite often.

Answer (score 2):

Then better to use `Hashmap<String, String>`. You can pass Hashmap in body directly, by parsing using Gson. 
And if you need to use multiple place then you can use your own map extending HashMap, so you will be able to add your values in one line. I am posting mine, might it help you -

```
public class PostParams extends HashMap<String, String> {
    public static PostParams init() {
        return new PostParams();
    }

    public PostParams add(String param, String value) {
        put(param, value);
        return this;
    }

    public PostParams add(String param, String[] values) {
        put(param, new Gson().toJson(values));
        return this;
    }

    public PostParams add(String param, int[] values) {
        put(param, new Gson().toJson(values));
        return this;
    }

    public PostParams add(String param, int value) {
        put(param, value + "");
        return this;
    }

    public PostParams addPlatform() {
        put("Platform", Constants.ANDROID);
        return this;
    }

    public PostParams add(String param, double value) {
        put(param, new Gson().toJson(value));
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}
```

Usage will be like -

```
String postData = new PostParams().add("bar", "Hello World").toString()
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I use like this:

```
@POST("url")
Observable<Response<Object>> login(@Body Map<String, Object> body);
```

It will change the Map into JsonObject